# Chaining State Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I have a function

```
step :: Int -> State Int Int
step n = get >>= \x ->  put  (x `div` n) >> return (x `mod` n)

λ> runState (step 25) 41
(16,1)
```

How do I run a sequence of `step`s, with different values of `n` and each step using the state from the last step?

so for example the steps would be as follows

step one  yields `(16,1)` which I then want to use as input for my next step with `n = 10` which should yield `(6, 2)`. With the 1 from the first step being added to and the 16 in step one being mod with the new n.

```
n = 25 gives (16,1) then
n = 10 gives (6,2)  then
n = 5  gives (1,3) then
n = 1 gives (0,4)
```

I am aware that using `State` here might not be correct; but I am trying to use it as a way to learn.

may aim is to implement this function with the state monad.

```
greedy :: Double -> Int
greedy owed = snd $ foldl go (pennies,0) [25, 10, 5, 1]
  where
    pennies                     = floor . (*100) $ owed
    go (remaining,counter) coin = (remaining',counter')
      where
        remaining' = remaining `mod` coin
        counter'   = counter + remaining `div` coin
```

Comment: Are you talking about anything other than `step 1 >> step 2 >> step 3`?

Comment: @Cubic, I have amended my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function,

```
mapM step [25,10,5,1]
```

or the more general

```
traverse step [25,10,5,1]
```

runs `step` on each of the list of `[25,10,5,1]`. Invoking

```
runState  (mapM step [25,10,5,1]) 41
```

runs the function with the initial state set to `41`, returning the list of step outputs and the final state.

```
([16,1,0,0],0)
```

If you want to list the states along with the output, just modify `step` to include them.

```
step n = get >>= \x ->  put  (x `div` n) >> return ((x `mod` n),(x `div` n))
```

or, put another way

```
step n = do 
  x <- get
  let (r,x') = (x `mod` n,x `div` n)
  put  x'
  return (r,x')
```

The result is, `([(16,1),(1,0),(0,0),(0,0)],0)`, still not what you are looking for, but closer. I'm afraid I don't understand the particulars of your equation well enough to get what you are looking for, but this should help sort out the State part, allowing you to focus on the math.

To make the above `go` function:

```
go n = do
   (r,c) <- get
   let (r',c') = (r `mod` n, c + (r `div` n))
   put (r',c')
   return (r',c')
```

and

```
runState (mapM go [25,10,5,1]) (41,0)
```

yields,

```
([(16,1),(6,2),(1,3),(0,4)],(0,4))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: my mistake, answered without testing, sorry. its only returning the outputs, will post fix.

Comment: any chance you can explain how the traverse works in this case. Sorry, I have really hit a wall with State Monad just can't get my head around it. I don't get what is being (or how it is being) passed to `step` at each point.

Comment: How do I get the  final value from the first result and use it for the second? I seem to only be able to access the state in this way?

Comment: I shouldn't have brought up traverse, just more confusion for you. Traverse works the same as mapM in this case, but you can also use it for mapping monadic functions over things which are not lists, but are list like enough. For example Trees.

Comment: what I mean re; traverse or mapM was that I dont see how it uses the previous value at each step. (and the results suggest it actually isnt??)

Comment: @matthias `step n >> step m` makes `step m` be run on the state as modified by `stem n`. `traverse` and the like is not that different. The state monad always carries an implicit state mutable variable with it -- that's its goal.

Comment: The inclusion of greedy in the question is helpful. I reimplemented go by just making the state the accumulator term.

Comment: thank you! It helps. Although I think I am going to continue to struggle with the State Monad. (There seems to be no simple (enough) examples of its use) :( Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, it might take a while. You are